# All Safari Tabs lost after installation of Mojave

Tags: safari, install, mojave

I had a lot of research tabs open in Safari. But all lost after installing Mojave.

I have Time Machine if that is of any help. I also checked "restoring all tabs from last session" without any success.

I'm a doomed or is there help? Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I can only guess here, but it might be worthwhile to look at `~/Library/Saved\ Application\ State/com.apple.Safari.savedState/` (that's a symlink to `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Safari/Data/Library/Saved\ Application\ State/com.apple.Safari.savedState/`). It seems the information is saved as raw data (except one general plist file, maybe that can at least give you some hints), but perhaps you can simply replace that from a TimeMachine backup. Be careful with that however, perhaps the reason why the tabs are gone in the first place was a change in the data format.

If that does not work you can try to look through your history (⌘-Y in Safari), though that's gonna be tedious.